# How to grab a letter after ';' with regular expressions?

Tags: regex, python-2.7

How can I grab a letter after `;` using regular expressions? For example:

```
c ; d
e ; f ; m ; k ; s
```

---

```
import re
f = open('file.txt')
regex = re.compile(r"(?<=\; )\w+")
for line in f:
    match = regex.search(line)
    if match: 
        print match.group()
```

This code only grabs `d` and `f`. I need the outcome yo look like:

```
d
f
m
k
s
```

Comment: From your example it looks like you want to simply delete those ";" characters. That can be better solved by other tools (ie. string replacement). Please clarify what **grab** means in this context.

Comment: Why do you want to use a regular expression for this? Why not just substitute all semicolons for newline characters?

Comment: @David: That won't eliminate the space before `d`, the updated question better highlights what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Replace all occurrences of *"; "* to a *newline* character and trim all spaces from the ends of every line.

Answer (score 0):

use a regex similar to this if you want to "blacklist" the ";" character:

```
[;]
```

I don't know much about python, but here how you would use it in JavaScript:

```
var desired_chars = myString.replace(/[;]/gi, '')
```

Comment: If you replace the ";" with an empty string, there will be 2 spaces between `e` and `f`. If you replace them with a _newline, then a space will remain before the letter _d_ => ` d`.

Comment: Hrm no. I just had the negate ^ that was wrong, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/HVj3R/

Comment: Or just do another regex to replace double space with single space :)

Comment: He needs every character in a new line. (Uh-oh, he left a space after the last character, now does he really need that extra space :-) or it is just a typo?)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `regex.search` use `regex.findall`. That'll give you a list of matches for each line which you can then manipulate and print on separate lines.